# C# .NET - How can I create a new Bitmap instance for a bitmap from native resources?

Tags: c#, bitmap, resources, native, unmanaged

I tried many times to load a Bitmap from native resources but I failed big time.

The image I'm trying to load is like this into the native resources:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7Jr8.jpg

The code I wrote the image with is this:

```
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern int UpdateResource(uint hUpdate, SqlDbType lpStructure, uint lpName, ushort wLanguage, int lpData, UIntPtr cbData);
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern UIntPtr BeginUpdateResource(string pFileName, bool bDeleteExistingResources);
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern bool EndUpdateResource(UIntPtr hUpdate, bool fDiscard);
public static bool WriteResource(string FileName, byte[] data, uint Name)
{
    UIntPtr ptr = BeginUpdateResource(FileName, false);
    GCHandle Handle = GCHandle.Alloc(data, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    uint size = Convert.ToUInt32(Convert.ToUInt64(data.Length));
    UIntPtr pt = new UIntPtr(size);
    UpdateResource(ptr.ToUInt32(), SqlDbType.Bit, Name, 0, Handle.AddrOfPinnedObject().ToInt32(), (UIntPtr)Convert.ToUInt64(data.Length));
    EndUpdateResource(ptr, false);
    return true;
}
```

I tried to use LoadImage and LoadBitmap API calls but I failed big time.

Can you provide me with a snippet on how I can do this conversion? I want to fetch it from the native resources and store it into a Bitmap class (the common System.Drawing.Bitmap class of .NET framework). I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I've understood you correctly. But I could imagine you are searching for something like this:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly thisExe;
thisExe = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
System.IO.Stream file = 
thisExe.GetManifestResourceStream("AssemblyName.ImageFile.jpg");
this.pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(file);
```

Comment: No sir, this is not what I am looking for. I am trying to read a bitmap from unmanaged resources.

Comment: Ok, sorry for the unnecessary answer.

Comment: It's okay sir, if you know a way to help me please tell me. I edited my main post with more info.